# Recasting column types with a function and a dictionary in pyspark

Tags: python, function, loops, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a large dataset with many columns. I want to write a function, using pyspark, which does the following:

-> I define a dictionary with columnnames (values) and datatypes (keys)
-> Look up the columns from the dataframe in the dictionary
-> If a column is found in a category, use the key of that category to cast a columntype

I got the function so far that it does not throw an error, Unfortunatelly, the function does not change the column types. I could not find the mistake. Can someone maybe spot the problem? Thanks :)

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, IntegerType, ArrayType

# This creates a sample dataframe
simpleData = [("James", "Sales", 3000),
    ("Michael", "Sales", 4600),
    ("Robert", "Sales", 4100),
    ("Kumar", "Marketing", 2000),
    ("Saif", "Sales", 4100)]
schema = ["employee_name", "department", "salary"]
table = spark.createDataFrame(data=simpleData, schema=schema)

# This is the function which is supposed to change datatypes en bulk
def recasting_function(data):
    df = data

    column_types = {
        "StringType()": ["employee_name", "department"],
        "IntegerType()": ["salary"]
        }

    for column in df.columns:
        if column in column_types.items():
            df = df.withColumn(item, df.item.cast(key))
    
    return df
        
# Here I apply it to my sample dataset
result = recasting_function(table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that `item` and `key` in your code are undefined variables, but it doesn't throw any error because the `if` clause is always False.  Try the code below:

```
# This creates a sample dataframe
simpleData = [("James", "Sales", 3000),
    ("Michael", "Sales", 4600),
    ("Robert", "Sales", 4100),
    ("Kumar", "Marketing", 2000),
    ("Saif", "Sales", 4100)]
schema = ["employee_name", "department", "salary"]
table = spark.createDataFrame(data=simpleData, schema=schema)

# This is the function which is supposed to change datatypes en bulk
def recasting_function(data):
    column_types = {
        "string": ["employee_name", "department"],
        "int": ["salary"]
        }
    for (k, v) in column_types.items():
        for c in v:
            if c in data.columns:
                data = data.withColumn(c, data[c].cast(k))    
    return data
        
# Here I apply it to my sample dataset
result = recasting_function(table)
```